# Allow CDATA in ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cdata

I'm removing html stuff with well known

```
ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(value)
```

method. It works well, however, when `value` passed into the method is wrapped in `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` return value is blank. How can I prevent this method from reacting to CDATA?

What I tried is putting this inside application.rb

```
config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_tags = ["![CDATA[", "]]"]
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't work, because [CDATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) is not a tag, it's an entity, and it usually belong to XML documents rather than HTML documents. If you [dig deep enough](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer/blob/670fd7a9a2667d824a6c1b271989a4fd4ed51cb6/lib/rails/html/sanitizer.rb#L24-L33), you will see, that `Rails::Html::FullSanitizer` uses [`Loofah`](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah) under the hood, i.e. it's `#fragment` method which delegates to parsing passed string as HTML Document Fragment, which ignores all CDATA sections under the hood.

```
# === Rails::Html::FullSanitizer
# Removes all tags but strips out scripts, forms and comments.
#
# full_sanitizer = Rails::Html::FullSanitizer.new
# full_sanitizer.sanitize("<b>Bold</b> no more!  <a href='more.html'>See more here</a>...")
# # => Bold no more!  See more here...
class FullSanitizer < Sanitizer
  def sanitize(html, options = {})
    return unless html
    return html if html.empty?

    Loofah.fragment(html).tap do |fragment|
      remove_xpaths(fragment, XPATHS_TO_REMOVE)
    end.text(options)
  end
end
```

So, the solution is just to use `Loofah` directly, like this:

```
text = "<div>in div</div> just text <![CDATA[ in cdata ]]> <script>alert(1);</script> <form>some form</form> <!-- some comments also -->"
# => "<div>in div</div> just text <![CDATA[ in cdata ]]> <script>alert(1);</script> <form>some form</form> <!-- some comments also -->"
Loofah.scrub_xml_fragment(text, :prune).text
# => "in div just text  in cdata   some form "
```

The result of this code slightly different from what `FullSanitizer` produces as the latter also removes all `<form>` tags, when my code doesn't. If that is critical to you, you can combine this code with `remove_xpaths` code above (see [link](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer/blob/670fd7a9a2667d824a6c1b271989a4fd4ed51cb6/lib/rails/html/sanitizer.rb#L24-L33)).

Comment: @Leo, please have a look, let me know if this code fixes your problem.

Comment: @dodge901 What did you find so offensive in my post? I don't have a glue at all, please, suggest an edit and I'll gladly accept it.